# dd script with timings

Tags: linux, rm, dd, time

Trying to figure out the best approach to a script that will do the following:

1. Create a loop script that creates a 10GB file using dd where, upon completion, removes the file, then repeats 25 times or if CTRL+C is typed before the script gets the chance to exit.
2. At the end of each operation, i.e. dd, then rm, time it so we know exactly how long dd and rm took

So far, I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
for i in {1..25}
  do
    time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=/user/home/test.img bs=10G count=1" >> /tmp/dd_timed.txt && time sh -c "rm -f /user/home/test.img" >> rm_timed.txt
done
```

Anyone have a better solution or could maybe tweak this a bit?

Comment: Do not set `bs=10G count=1`; it will uselessly eat up a lot of RAM that way. Set `bs=1G count=10`. Or set `bs=16M count=10G iflag=count_bytes` for greater flexibility.

Comment: Ok.  Understood - thanks for the suggestion.  One of the problems is that it doesn't appear dd or rm are writing to /tmp within the files specified.  They're literally zero bytes.  I saw on another forum how, instead of using a single > redirect, one had to use 2> because of something funky that time was doing, but I'm trying to append because I need to know how long each iteration of dd and rm are taking.

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably have to do `2>>/tmp/whatever` as time prints statistics to standard error. In fact, if you're using `bash`, you'll even have to put time in a subshell: `( time ... ) 2>>/tmp/...`. Or use the real `/usr/bin/time ... 2>//tmp/...`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it looks like here's the way to get this done.  Looks nasty, but works:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..25}
do
{ time dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/user/test.img bs=1G count=10 oflag=direct >& / dev/null ; } 2>> /tmp/dd_timed.txt && { time rm /home/user/test.img >& /dev/null ;  } 2>> /tmp/rm_timed.txt
done
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be interesting to compare the time used by

```
time ( dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test.img bs=1M count=1024; sync )
```

and

```
time ( dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test.img bs=1M count=1024 oflag=direct;sync )
```

You should include `sync` in order to measure the time to finish writing to the target device.

In my main computer it is [15-20%] faster to use `oflag=direct`, when writing to a SATA SSD (where my `/tmp` is located).

---

However, there can be problems with `oflag=direct`, see the following link,

[Why not always use 'oflag=direct' in 'dd'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/713301/why-not-always-use-oflag-direct-in-dd)