# Why not always use 'oflag=direct' in 'dd'?

Tags: dd, io

Using `oflag=direct` in `dd` seems always to make operations much faster than either not using it, or using `pv` etc. to do the operation instead.

Under what circumstances might I **not** want to use `oflag=direct`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just off the top of my head:

- If the destination file is mmapped by another process, then using direct IO to write to it may result in data loss (usually of the direct IO writes).
- Some filesystems either don’t support direct IO, or do not work correctly with direct IO. The second possibility was historically the case with BTRFS under some circumstances, and you would end up with data corruption in the target file sometimes when using direct IO.
- Direct IO is not universally faster. There are a bunch of things at play here, but as a general rule the common case where direct IO is slower is dealing with copying files small enough to fit into the system writeback cache to slow storage with non-zero seek latency.
- Sometimes it’s desirable for the side-effects of regular IO to happen. This is potentially useful for example if the destination file is on slow storage and you plan to use it immediately, in which case not using direct IO means that at least some of the file data will probably still be in the page cache, saving time when subsequently reading the file. It’s also important if you’re trying to do performance benchmarking, because many things don’t use direct IO.
- If you need to be truly portable, you cannot rely on the availability of `oflags=direct`, because it’s a Linux-specific extension.